# Confidence intervals statistics question

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ be the service time of employee $1$ and $2$.For random sample $n_{1}=8$ for employee $1$ the average service time $\bar{x_{1}} = 181.6 $ and for random sample $n_{2}=10$ for employee $2$  the average service time $\bar{x_{2}} = 141.5$.It is given that $\sigma_{1}^{2} = \sigma_{2}^{2}=40$ and $P(Z>=1.96) = 0.025$,$P(Z>=1.64)=0.05$. Find a 95% confidence interval of the difference between the service times of employees 1 and 2.

I was thinking of applying this formula:

$\bar{x_{1}}-\bar{x_{2}}-z_{0.975}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1}^{2}}{n_{1}^2}+\frac{\sigma_{2}^{2}}{n_{2}^2}}<=\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}<=\bar{x_{1}}-\bar{x_{2}}+z_{0.975}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1}^{2}}{n_{1}^2}+\frac{\sigma_{2}^{2}}{n_{2}^2}}$

But it doesnt give me $z_{0.975}$.How can I find $z_{0.975}$ from $P(Z>=1.1.96) = 0.025$,$P(Z>=1.64)=0.05$?

Comment: What are the values for $n_1$ and $n_2$? These missing values would me bothering first.

Comment: And $P(Z\leq 1.96)=1-0.025=0.975$. Thus $z_{0.975}=1.96$

Comment: Question editted.

Comment: Your two sided confidence interval looks fine. With my comments you can finish it.